# Mixed Linear Model Regression missing output

Tags: mixed-model, statsmodels, pandas

I'm running a mixed linear model regression and I get some missing output and for the one I get it doesn't make too much sense (or at least I think so as the p-value is always equal to 1). The columns "females" and "males" are one-hot encoded. Does that make any difference? (nothing changed when defining them as categorical variables C(females) for example)

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

variables = "(parameter1 + parameter2)"

md = smf.mixedlm("var1 ~  {} + females + females*{} + males + males*{} ".format(variables, variables, variables), df, groups=df["ids"])

mdf = md.fit()
print(mdf.summary())
```

Output:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                     Coef.    Std.Err.    z    P>|z|    [0.025       0.975]  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept             0.390                                                  
males                 3.053                                                  
females               3.086                                                  
parameter1            1.073                                                  
parameter2            0.386  563735.025  0.000 1.000 -1104899.960 1104900.733
males:parameter1     -1.147                                                  
males:parameter2     -0.329  563735.025 -0.000 1.000 -1104900.676 1104900.017
females:parameter1    1.311  981689.591  0.000 1.000 -1924074.933 1924077.554
females:parameter2    2.019
```

Half of the output is missing and I get a p-value always equal to 1?

Comment: The Hessian matrix of the log-likelihood is singular at the RMLE.  This means that the estimated variance/covariance matrix of the parameters may have non-positive diagonal values.  These non-positive values are omitted in the output for standard errors, z-scores, etc.  even though the parameter estimates are still available.